# Assigning a database value to a variable in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I am very new to Postgres development and want to write a function (spUserTest) to look up a value and then use that value to extract data from a table.

My code runs as follows:

**Table Definition**

```
-- auto-generated definition
create table "user"
(
    userid         uuid not null
        constraint pk__user__1788ccac19748a10
            primary key
        constraint uq__user__1788ccad4f14aa65
            unique,
    username       varchar(100)
        constraint uq__user__c9f2845657920267
            unique,
    passwordhash   bytea,
    firstname      varchar(40),
    lastname       varchar(40),
    salt           uuid,
    organisationid uuid
        constraint fk_user_organisation_organisationid
            references organisation,
    sessiontoken   uuid,
    sessionage     timestamp with time zone
);

alter table "user"
    owner to postgres;

-- auto-generated definition
create table userdevice
(
    userdeviceid uuid not null
        constraint pk__userdevi__fd151c39ccac5a1d
            primary key,
    userid       uuid
        constraint fkuser_userdevice_userid
            references "user",
    deviceid     uuid
        constraint fkuser_userdevice_deviceid
            references device,
    constraint unique_userid_deviceid
        unique (userid, deviceid)
);

alter table userdevice
    owner to postgres;
```

**spUserTest Function**

```
create function spuserTest(username2 text)
    returns TABLE(UserDeviceID uuid, UserID uuid, DeviceID uuid)
    language sql
as
 do $$

  declare
       UserID2     uuid;

begin

    UserID2 := (SELECT t.userid from dbo.user t where t.username = username2);

RETURN QUERY
        SELECT
            UserDeviceID ::text,
            UserID  ::text,
            DeviceID ::text
        FROM
            dbo.userdevice
        where
            UserID = UserID2;

END $$;
```

So within the function spUserTest, I want to do the following:

1. Use username2 to look up the Userid from the User table
2. Then use the value for userID , to extract data from the table UserDevice

But when I run this , I get the following error:

```
[2023-10-31 12:18:38] [42601] ERROR: syntax error at end of input
[2023-10-31 12:18:38] Position: 131
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Remove the `do` and change `sql` to `plpgsql`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PL/pgSQL you don't (usually) assign the result of a SELECT into a variable - you use a SELECT..INTO statement.

So replace

```
UserID2 := (SELECT t.userid from dbo.user t where t.username = username2);
```

with

```
SELECT t.userid
  INTO UserID2
  from dbo.user t
  where t.username = username2;
```

Another option would be to eliminate the separate fetch of `UserID2` entirely and embed the `dbo.user` query into the main query:

```
SELECT  
        UserDeviceID ::text,
        UserID  ::text,
        DeviceID ::text
    FROM
        dbo.userdevice
    where
        UserID IN (SELECT userid
                     from dbo.user
                     where username = username2)
```